# htaccess file path to array

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory

I don't do much with htaccess, usually using frameworks that already have it made. I've checked multiple sites to learn htaccess, but they all come across a bit tricky to grasp. I've tried a few garbled messes, and looking elsewhere on stackoverflow, I've found some that do the first directory or a limited set, but not any further, and I'm not having luck.

What I'm looking for is to do this...

The user types in (or browses to) one of the following into their address bar...

```
example.com
example.com/foo/bar/
example.com/some/really/long/set/of/directories/.../that/seems/to/go/on/forever
```

And for it to end up all redirected to be processed by

```
example.com/index.php
```

with an array filled with the path such as

```
// in index.php
print_r (myarray);
// printing something like...
// []
// or
// ["foo", "bar"]
// or
// ["some", "really", "long", "set", "of", "directories", ... , "that", "seems", "to", "go", "on", "forever"]
// respectively.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably capture everything after the host portion and append it to a `dir` variable in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^example.com(.*) http://example.com?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Or:

```
RewriteRule ^%{HTTP_HOST}(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then in your PHP you could use `$_GET['dir']` as needed:

```
$array = explode('/', $_GET['dir']);
```

Comment: Hmm... not working for me, but may be a problem with my site. I'll have to mess around with it for a bit.

Comment: Found part of the problem was that I needed `RewriteEngine on`, however it's giving me 404's instead of redirecting to index.php

Comment: Is there a certain rewrite condition that needs to be tied with the rule to make that work?